# Winform Application Auto-Maximizes on Win 8.1 Tablet

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8.1

I have a small winform utility app that is forced to open maximized on a new Win 8.1 tablet.  I'm sure this is a compatibility feature on Win 8.1, but is there anyway to prevent it from occurring?

The app has no maximize button and the border style is FixedSingle.

Comment: Click the form in the designer (preferably the title bar) and check the Properties toolbar, there are options (I can't remember the names) to change the width, height, initial position and stuff like that.

Comment: I believe the application is fine.  At least on every other Windows machine I can test it on, the window behaves normally.  

This is some "feature" in the latest version of Windows 8.1 running on a tablet.  I just want to know how to disable this feature.

Comment: Here is someone else describing the same [issue](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/65555-how-stop-windows-auto-maximizing-when-they-opened.html).

Comment: @JoeWezensky Hi, did you found out how to fix it?